# How to grow parent height div based on absolute child's height

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I'm trying to achieve the following layout in a Gatbsy(React) application. I have looking like that. The problem is that the white square depending on the content the height will change. If this height changes the height of the blue needs to change as well. The page needs to to always look essentially like the picture attach, meaning no matter the height of the white square, it always need to be a little above the blue square.

**I'm using Sass(SCSS).**

**CodePen:**
https://codepen.io/devpato/pen/ZEYwexw

[image]

**CSS**

```
 .header, .footer {
      width: 100%;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: green;
    }

    .blue {
      position: relative;
      /* Height can't have a set value */
      height: 400px;
      background-color: blue;
      width: 100%;

      .white {
      height: 400px;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: white;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      margin: 0 auto;
      top: -24px;
      width:  80%;
     }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="blue">
       <div class="white"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you forcing to set child div as a absolute, for overlapping parent?

Comment: @Hanif correct! for overlapping the top green square...ofcourse. if you have a better way to achive this, I'm open  to it :)

Comment: Then just remove the parent height and keep the child height and set child as a relative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then just remove the parent height and keep the child height and set child as a relative like following:

```
.blue {
  position: relative;
  /* Hight can't have a set value */
  /*height: 400px;*/
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  .white {
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: -24px;
    width:  80%;
 }
}
```

Also see here: [codepenexample](https://codepen.io/markupsolution/pen/dyPavxN)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the height from parent and add position relative in child instead of absolute

```
.blue {
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  .white {
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: -24px;
  width:  80%;
 }
}
```